# call rsource with arguments

Tags: r, arguments, stata

I am using `rsource` command to call R within Stata in order to create one random vector and return it to stata, simple working example of my do file:

```
clear
rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)  rpath(C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\R.exe) roptions("--vanilla")
            set.seed(1234);
            library(mvtnorm);
            library(tmvtnorm);
            library(foreign);

            xmean<- rep(0,100);
            xSigma<- diag(100);
            a<- rep(0,100);
            b<- rep(+Inf,100);
            X<- rtmvnorm(n=1, 
                         mean=xmean, sigma=xSigma, 
                         lower=a, upper=b, 
                         algorithm="gibbs");
            X<- t(X);

            write.dta(data.frame(X), "C:/Users/.../Desktop/all/newx.dta");
            END_OF_R

use newx.dta, replace
```

Is it possible to pass some values to `rsource` as arguments, which i could define in stata (such as for example rseed number or N-number of obs). For example:

```
cap prog drop callr
program callr
version 13
    syntax , seed(int) n(int)
    .... to call rsource with `seed' and `n' as arguments
use newx.dta, replace 
end
```

I am pretty new in this, and couldn't find and answer in rsource help or interne, so any comment is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass Stata macro values to R using the `roptions` option. An example of two local macros being passed:

```
clear

local mynumber 999
local secondone 1000

rsource, terminator(END_OF_R) rpath("/usr/bin/R") roptions(`" --vanilla --args "`mynumber'" "`secondone'" "')

trailargs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE);
trailargs;

trailargs[1];
trailargs[2];

END_OF_R
```

This is documented in `help rsource`. See also `help macro` if that concept is not clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, rsource help is not too much clear for someone who is trying to apply it for the first time....it is working now, after i transfer them into numbers(`n<- as.numeric(trailargs[1]` ...)